# Can't upload tvOS app to App Store

Tags: app-store-connect, tvos, xcode7.2, tvos9.1

Getting the error:

> New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions
>   of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and tvOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with
>   beta software including beta OS X builds.

when trying to upload tvOS app to appstore, I am using Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002), OSX 10.11.3 (15D21), and DTSDKBuild/DTPlatformBuild 13U79.

Which of these needs changing? I was under the impression that none of these versions are beta

Comment: try using applicaiton loader, xcode 7 have some issues

Comment: Can also download Xcode 7.2 to get around the issue in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a long thread over on the [Apple Dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/35104) about it. I opened a radar as well. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon, but really surprised it's been going on for this long already.

UPDATE: Radar hasn't been updated and still seeing issue, so I decided to try something out:
1) Go here and download Xcode 7.2 https://developer.apple.com/downloads/
2) Install 7.2
3) Rebuild project
4) Upload archive
5) Submit app for review - success!

If you have an update that you need to get out, looks like this is a workaround.

UPDATE 2: There is a new post on Apple Dev forums with someone who said they were able to submit with build from 7.2.1 so it could be resolved.